# How to loop without get Illegal string offset

Tags: php

Even record is insert correctly im still getting this error and cant find where the problem is

the error is come for both INSERT INTO but when i check in DB record is there and its correct so how to deal with this error ?

here is my code and dumps

```
$order_id = $this->db->getLastId();
if ($data['options'] != '') {
        foreach ($data['options'] as $filter => $option) {
            $check = $this->db->query("SELECT
                                            oc_product_option.option_id,
                                            oc_option.type,
                                            oc_option_description.name,
                                            oc_product_option_value.option_value_id,
                                            oc_option_value_description.name AS option_name
                                            FROM oc_product_option
                                            LEFT JOIN oc_option ON (oc_product_option.option_id = oc_option.option_id)
                                            LEFT JOIN oc_option_description ON (oc_product_option.option_id = oc_option_description.option_id)
                                            LEFT JOIN oc_product_option_value ON (oc_product_option_value.product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option . "')
                                            LEFT JOIN oc_option_value_description ON (oc_option_value_description.option_value_id = oc_product_option_value.option_value_id)
                                            WHERE oc_product_option.product_option_id = '" . (int)$filter . "'
                                            AND oc_product_option.product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "'");
            foreach ($check->rows as $option_type) {

                if ($option_type['type'] == 'custom') {
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "fast_order_option SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', order_product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "', product_option_id = '" . (int)$filter . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($option_type['name']) . "', value = '" . $this->db->escape($option) . "', type = '" . $this->db->escape($option['type']) . "'");
                }else {
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "fast_order_option SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', order_product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "', product_option_id = '" . (int)$filter . "', product_option_value_id = '" . $this->db->escape($option) . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($option_type['name']) . "', value = '" . $this->db->escape($option_type['option_name']) . "', type = '" . $this->db->escape($option['type']) . "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

$data['options']

```
Array
(
[1330] => 1853
[1181] => 2
[1182] => 1
[1179] => 1660
)
```

$check

```
stdClass Object
(
[num_rows] => 1
[row] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 16
        [type] => select
        [name] => Двулицев Размер
        [option_value_id] => 56
        [option_name] => 300/100
    )

[rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [option_id] => 16
                [type] => select
                [name] => Двулицев Размер
                [option_value_id] => 56
                [option_name] => 300/100
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: And _where_ do you get this error?

Comment: for  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "fast_order_option SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', order_product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "', product_option_id = '" . (int)$filter . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($option_type['name']) . "', value = '" . $this->db->escape($option) . "', type = '" . $this->db->escape($option['type']) . "'");

Comment: you didn't defined `$order_id` anywhere in your code, but that used in query

Comment: The warning means that you're using a string key in an array somewhere that doesn't exist. But the code is incomplete, so I cannot tell which one it is.

Comment: i did it sorry forget to post is $order_id = $this->db->getLastId();

Comment: `$option['type']` at the end should probably be `$option_type['type']` - `$option` is from your outer foreach loop, and contains one of your integers from $data['options'] at this point.

Comment: @04FS gratz that was the problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    type = '" . $this->db->escape($option['type']) . "'");
}
```

`$option['type']` at the end there should be `$option_type['type']` - `$option` is from your outer foreach loop, and contains one of your integers from `$data['options']` at this point.